# Parsing html with correct encoding

Tags: python, encoding, beautifulsoup, utf-8, python-requests

I'm trying to use the [basketball-reference](http://basketball-reference.com) API using python with the `requests` and `bs4` libraries.

```py
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Here's a minimal example of what I'm trying to do:

```py
# example request
r = get(f'https://widgets.sports-reference.com/wg.fcgi?css=1&site=bbr&url=%2Fteams%2FMIL%2F2015.html&div=div_roster')
soup = BeautifulSoup(dd.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table')
```

It all works well, I can then feed this `table` to `pandas` with its `read_html` and get the data I need nicely packed into a dataframe.

**The problem I have is the encoding.**

In this particular request I got two NBA player names with weird characters: `Ersan &Auml;&deg;lyasova` ([Ersan İlyasova](https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/i/ilyaser01.html)) and `Jorge Guti&Atilde;&copy;rrez` ([Jorge Gutiérrez](https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/g/gutiejo01.html)). In the current code they are interpreted as "Ersan Ä°lyasova" and "Jorge GutiÃ©rrez", which is obviously not what I want.

So the question is -- how do I fix it? [This website](https://2cyr.com/decode) seems to suggest they have the `windows-1251` encoding, but I'm not sure how to use that information (in fact I'm not even sure if that's true).

I know I'm missing something fundamental here as I'm a bit confused how these encodings work at which point they are being "interpreted" etc, so I'll be grateful if you help me with this!

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know why you are using`format string` and even your question is not clear. you've just copy/paste the url from the network traffic and then you mixing things about quoted string with encoding.

Below you should be able to done it.

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_html("https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/MIL/2015.html")

print(df)
```

Output:

```
[    No.                   Player Pos  ... Unnamed: 6  Exp                College   
0    34    Giannis Antetokounmpo  SG  ...         gr    1                    NaN    
1    19           Jerryd Bayless  PG  ...         us    6                Arizona    
2     5  Michael Carter-Williams  PG  ...         us    1               Syracuse    
3     9             Jared Dudley  SG  ...         us    7         Boston College    
4    11              Tyler Ennis  PG  ...         ca    R               Syracuse    
5    13          Jorge Gutiérrez  PG  ...         mx    1             California    
6    31              John Henson   C  ...         us    2                    UNC    
7     7           Ersan İlyasova  PF  ...         tr    6                    NaN    
8    23            Chris Johnson  SF  ...         us    2                 Dayton    
9    11           Brandon Knight  PG  ...         us    3               Kentucky    
10    5         Kendall Marshall  PG  ...         us    2                    UNC    
11    6            Kenyon Martin  PF  ...         us   14             Cincinnati    
12    0                O.J. Mayo  SG  ...         us    6                    USC    
13   22          Khris Middleton  SF  ...         us    2              Texas A&M    
14    3          Johnny O'Bryant  PF  ...         us    R                    LSU    
15   27            Zaza Pachulia   C  ...         ge   11                    NaN    
16   12            Jabari Parker  PF  ...         us    R                   Duke    
17   21            Miles Plumlee   C  ...         us    2                   Duke    
18    8            Larry Sanders   C  ...         us    4  Virginia Commonwealth    
19    6             Nate Wolters  PG  ...         us    1     South Dakota State
```

Comment: thanks. this might indeed work. the reason i'm complicating things is that i was actually trying to fix this library: https://github.com/vishaalagartha/basketball_reference_scraper.